# m2e is adding source folders from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm developing a Java SDK with Eclipse and Maven. 
I want to insert inside the final ZIP deploy package some example sources written with my SDK.
So I did the following:
- In my project, I created a new folder: src/examples/java
- I set this folder as a source folder in Eclipse
The problem is that this folder is also compiled and the final class files are added to the packaged JAR file (this is not what I want, these files are managed by the assembly plugin). It seems that m2e is doing something with my POM...

Comment: why don't you put those examples in e.g. `src/main/resources/examples`? This way they won't be compiled, yet they will be packaged in your deployable.

Comment: Thanks Francesco, the problem is that doing this, Java wants my packages starting with "example.", which is not what I want. Setting the entire src/main/resources/examples as a source folder still copy the class files in the final JAR.

Comment: Oh, I get it.. You could try defining another resource section in your pom.xml, like this : `<resources><resource><directory>/src/examples/java</directory></resource></resources>`. However, if you define the folder as a source folder, i think you'll have to define some `excludes` either in the pom or in eclipse's classpath definition.

Comment: That's a bit strange because a folder named src/examples/java (but src/main/examples, too) should not be included in the Maven default lifecycle...

Comment: You are right, but I wonder if m2e mixes up the source folders you define in eclipse's classpath with the ones used by maven. I'm just guessing here, but that could be an explanation..

Comment: Yes, I suppose you're right, because if I simply run "mvn clean package" from the Windows prompt, the produced jar file is ok. The question now is: how can I fix this on m2e? Thanks for now!

Comment: Another explanation could be that maven uses the eclipse compiler. If this is true, what happens is that eclipse compiles your examples and puts them in `target/classes`, then Maven picks them up for packaging. Try to uncheck auto-build in eclipse, then perform a maven clean and package and see if the result is different.

Comment: You can configure eclipse's classpath to output the compiled examples in `target/test-classes` (or another folder). This should prevent maven from packaging your compiled examples.

Comment: It seems working setting a different output path...that's not a "final" solution but that's great for my need. Thank you